# 90s-2000s anime about a girl and her father looking for gems

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime

I watched it when I was a kid in Bulgaria (on the channel "BNT 1" it could help). What I remember was a girl and her father looking for gems/stones around the world to add to a bracelet and at the end of each episode we could see the bracelet on a black background and the new gem adding to it. The world was kinda medieval fantasy but I really can't remember more and I'm not sure if they were really father and daughter but the girl was younger and the man had a beard, they both had brown hair.

Answer (score 7):

Is this ***[Deltora Quest](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0926230/)*** (2007–2010)...?

> Leif must restore the seven gems and the belt of Deltora to save his homeland. Along with his companions Barda and Jasmine, Lief must face devious enemies and dangerous beasts to oust the Shadow Lord and return peace to Deltora.

- The plot centres around a quest to find seven gems.
- It takes place in a medieval fantasy setting.
- Two of the three main characters are Jasmine, a girl with green hair, and Barda, an older man with brown hair and a beard. They aren't related, though.
- There's a shot of the belt of Deltora with the gems on it, on a dark background, at around the 0:38 mark in this video of the closing credits.

Comment: it's weirdly close to the description but I don't really that's the one :( the the girl and the older man were the only main characters and I don't remember a blond main character. The artstyle was more ghibli like and the world wasn't that fantastic